# Can I access app variable inside AppDelegate when app is in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native-ios, appdelegate

I am working on a chat app in react-native iOS. I want to show badge count in main app icon when new notification is received in background mode. Now I am able to show the badge count in main app icon. But it increases count for each notification. I want to restrict this based on chats. For this I need chat ids which have new message. Can I access app variables in **didReceiveRemoteNotification** method of Appdelegate.m when app is running in background?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your code is running you can access pretty much everything but there are some limitations.

The question here is what do you consider as "app variables". Most likely these are objects that are already in your memory and can be accessed in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` or any other method with no problem at all.

When they are not in your memory some limitations may occur but they are not necessary unreachable. Some cases that may or may not have issues:

- Reading from disk if files are encrypted by your OS
- Resources are on remote server and you need to communicate via internet
- Your data is on GPU or needs GPU to be processed

If your `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is already being called then you should have little or no trouble with that. But notifications do not necessarily trigger this method. The payload of a notification should already contain a badge count and your OS should be able to correctly display the badge instead of just always adding a value to it.

App may not just be in background. It may be suspended or even terminated. It is possible that your application will be awaken from notification and in that case you can not expect `didReceiveRemoteNotification` to be called. And even if it was you can not expect that you still have any information in your memory from previous calls; since your app was just relaunched there is nothing left in memory from previous run.